# Dependent variable with many zeros in a difference-in-differences model

Tags: bias, zero-inflation, difference-in-difference

There is a question with a similar title: [How do I estimate a differences in differences model when the dependent variable has many zeros?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35459/how-do-i-estimate-a-differences-in-differences-model-when-the-dependent-variable)

However, mine is a little different. Let's assume I have a dependent with 20% of zeros in the treatment group in the pre-treatment period; and 40% of zeros in the control group in the pre-treatment period. Then I observe that I have 10% of zeros in the treatment group in the post-treatment period and 30% of zeros in the control group in the post-treatment period (i.e. **in both case the proportion of zeros decreased by 10 percentage points**).

Is it wrong then to say that since both treatment and control groups have the same decrease in the number of zeros between the two periods, the difference-in-difference coefficient should not be biased?

Answer (score 1):

Not at all.

I see no reason why such result can be equivalent to the assumptions made for an unbiased estimator in diff-in-diff regressions, namely: 1) a correctly specified equation; 2) average of error term equals zero and 3) error term not correlated with independent variables (the paralell-trend assumption).

This result you observe do not replace any of these assumptions, let alone all of them.

Please refer to [these notes](https://eml.berkeley.edu/~webfac/saez/e131_s04/diff.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise enough. I already have a pre-treatment parallel trend. But my dependent variable includes a significant amount of zeros. I was wondering whether this was a problem for the validity of the diff-in-diff, knowing that the proportion of zeros in the treatment and control group decreases by 10 percentage points between the pre- and post-treatment periods (i.e. if there is a bias because of the zeros, it appears that this bias "evolves similarly" in the two group, so I wonder whether it cancels out or not).